# Receipt Printer doesn't Print In Windows Service

Tags: c#, printing, windows-services, receipt

I'm using PrintDocument Library to Print Receipt In Windows service  but it shows the printer and doesn't work or print anything,
but if I'm using the same code in console Application it's working fine without any problem
this my code :

```
public void PrintReceiptForTransaction()
{
    PrintDocument recordDoc = new PrintDocument();

    recordDoc.DocumentName = "Customer Receipt";
    recordDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintReceiptPage); // function below
    recordDoc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController(); // hides status dialog popup
                                                               // Comment if debugging 
    PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();           
    recordDoc.PrinterSettings = ps;
    recordDoc.Print();


    recordDoc.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is most likely a user session problem. The library may be using some code that requires a user session to run (possibly to find available printers?)

Comment: what did you mean by user session it's work and in debug mode i can see the default Printer but doesn't print .